# How to access a UserControl's parent resources in WinRt Xaml

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I have this xaml code:

```
<Common:LayoutAwarePage.Resources>
   <CollectionViewSource x:Name="cvs" IsSourceGrouped="true" />
</Common:LayoutAwarePage.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Full:TestSnapPage Name="MainView" />     
    ...
```

From within the codebehind of the UserControl, how can i access the CollectionViewSource?

Answer (score 2):

1. Bind `collectionviewsource` to Tag and access it from code behind

   ```
   < Full:TestSnapPage Name="MainView" Tag="{Binding Source={StaticResource cvs}}"/>
   ```
2. Walk up to Parent page, and access resources in code behind

   ```
           var parentPage = GetParentsPage(this); 
           if (parentPage != null)
           {
              //parentPage.Resources["cvs"]
           }

           private ParentPage GetParentsPage(FrameworkElement @this)
           { 
               FrameworkElement temp = @this;
               while (temp.Parent != null)
               {

                   if (temp.Parent is ParentPage)
                       return temp.Parent as ParentPage;

                   temp = temp.Parent as FrameworkElement;
               }
               return null;
           }
   ```
3. Use [MVVMLight](http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/) framework for communication between views (or between view models).

Comment: I've not had chance to try this yet, but hopefully i will later. Looks good, thanks!